# HSQLDB Serialization error with parallel JobSteps

Tags: java, concurrency, spring-batch, hsqldb, job-scheduling

I'm trying to get a complex flow of jobs done in Spring Batch using a combination of multithreaded Steps and parallel jobs.

Right now I've set up 3 jobs (1, 2, 3), the first (1) of which is running before the others (as expected) and completing withouth issues. The other two (2,3) are supposed to run parallel, having some parallel Steps of their own. All these jobs I'm trying to run are being encapsulated within JobSteps and then run within a master job (0).

The problem only occurs at jobs 2 & 3, where some JobStep fails, not always at the same point, not always the same JobStep. This is the stacktrace of such exception:

```
2019-01-07 17:35:57,513 ERROR: o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-10] Encountered an error executing step 2 in job0
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not increment identity; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: transaction rollback: serialization failure at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractIdentityColumnMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractIdentityColumnMaxValueIncrementer.java:113) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:128) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:145) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.JobStep.doExecute(JobStep.java:117) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:93) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:271) [spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: transaction rollback: serialization failure at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractIdentityColumnMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractIdentityColumnMaxValueIncrementer.java:110) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: transaction rollback: serialization failure at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.handleAbortTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractIdentityColumnMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractIdentityColumnMaxValueIncrementer.java:110) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 42 more
```

I've done a bit of research and this kind of error normally shows up when the HSQLDB I'm using to store job information isn't properly set up for concurrency. However I'm already using the seemingly good config, with MVCC transaction mode:

```
@Configuration
public class HSqlDbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean("hsqldbDataSource")
    public DataSource hsqldbDataSource() {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb;sql.enforce_strict_size=true;hsqldb.tx=mvcc");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

These are my code fragments I use for the configuration of these jobs. Beginning with the main job (0):

```
@Bean
public Job job0(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {

    getJobParameters();
    jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ctx.getBean("jobLauncher");

    Flow job1 = getJob1();
    Flow job2 = getJob2();
    Flow job3 = getJob3();


    Flow splitFlow = getSplitFlow(job2, job3);

    return  jobBuilderFactory.get("Master Job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(job1)
            .next(splitFlow)
            .end()
            .build();

}
```

How I get the Flow for jobs 2 & 3:

```
private Flow getJob2() {

    Job j2 = (Job) ctx.getBean("job2");

    DefaultJobParametersExtractor extractor = new DefaultJobParametersExtractor();

    Step step0 = getJobStep(j2, extractor);

    return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("job2")
            .start(step0)
            .build();
}

private Flow getJob3() {

    Job j3 = (Job) ctx.getBean("job3");
    Job j3k = (Job) ctx.getBean("job3K");
    Job j3l = (Job) ctx.getBean("job3L");

    DefaultJobParametersExtractor extractor = new DefaultJobParametersExtractor();

    Step step0 = getJobStep(j3, extractor);
    Step step1 = getJobStep(j3k, params1);
    Step step2 = getJobStep(j3k, params2);
    Step step3 = getJobStep(j3l, params3);
    Step step4 = getJobStep(j3l, params4);

    Flow flow1 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flowJ3f1")
            .start(step1)
            .next(step2)
            .build();

    Flow flow2 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flowJ3f2")
            .start(step3)
            .next(step4)
            .build();

    return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("job3")
            .start(step0)
            .split(taskExecutor)
            .add(flow1, flow2)
            .build();
}
```

Both getJobStep() methods:

```
private Step getJobStep(Job job, JobParametersExtractor extractor) {    
    return  steps.get(job.getName())
            .job(job)
            .launcher(jobLauncher)
            .parametersExtractor(extractor)
            .build();
}

private Step getJobStep(Job job, JobParameters jobParameters) {

    SimpleJobParametersExtractor extractor = new SimpleJobParametersExtractor();
    extractor.setJobParameters(jobParameters);

    return  steps.get(job.getName())
            .job(job)
            .launcher(jobLauncher)
            .parametersExtractor(extractor)
            .build();
}
```

The idea is to get this structure to work, as parallelization of all task possible is a requirement for this project, and it should be sturdy enough to add other parallel jobs apart from 2 & 3. Also, all jobs and steps have been tested without concurrency and they work as intended.

I can provide more code if needed. Right now I feel in a dead end so every bit of help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** As @MahmoudBenHassine suggested, I've configured a JobRepository, TransactionManager and JobLauncher (it solved my first issue) like so:

```
@Bean(name = "myTransactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("hsqldbDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}

@Bean(name = "myJobRepository")
public JobRepository jobRepository(@Qualifier("hsqldbDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        @Qualifier("myTransactionManager") DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager) throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(dataSourceTransactionManager);
    factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "myJobLauncher")
public JobLauncher getJobLauncher(@Qualifier("myJobRepository") JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

Then I run job 0 with the new JobLauncher and this exception occurs on the JobSteps from job3 (3K & 3L) **EDIT**: I've got a larger log extract to more context of what's happening:

```
2019-01-09 09:53:39,793 INFO: o.s.b.c.j.SimpleStepHandler [MainTaskExecutor11] Executing step: [3K]
2019-01-09 09:53:39,811 INFO: o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobLauncher [MainTaskExecutor11] Job: [FlowJob: [name=3K]] launched with the following parameters: [{process=Job 3K BAR, pos_cod=BAR, per_event=EVENT, isRet=false, UNIQUE=-2347943936040182027}]
2019-01-09 09:53:39,821 INFO: o.s.b.c.j.SimpleStepHandler [MainTaskExecutor11] Executing step: [[3K] Job 3K]
2019-01-09 09:53:39,822 INFO: e.i.l.d.l.StepListener [MainTaskExecutor11] Executing Step: [3K] Job 3K
2019-01-09 09:53:41,120 INFO: e.i.l.d.l.StepListener [MainTaskExecutor11] Write Count: 0
2019-01-09 09:53:41,166 INFO: o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobLauncher [MainTaskExecutor11] Job: [FlowJob: [name=3K]] completed with the following parameters: [{process=Job 3K BAR, pos_cod=BAR, per_event=EVENT, isRet=false, UNIQUE=-2347943936040182027}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2019-01-09 09:53:41,189 INFO: o.s.b.c.j.SimpleStepHandler [MainTaskExecutor11] Duplicate step [3K] detected in execution of job=[job 0]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2019-01-09 09:53:41,191 INFO: o.s.b.c.j.SimpleStepHandler [MainTaskExecutor11] Executing step: [3K]
2019-01-09 09:53:41,201 ERROR: o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep [MainTaskExecutor11] Encountered an error executing step 3K in job 0
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={process=Job 3K BAR, pos_cod=BAR, per_event=EVENT, isRet=false, UNIQUE=-2347943936040182027}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.JobStep.doExecute(JobStep.java:117) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:93) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
```

Please note I use different JobParameters in `getJob3()` for each execution of job 3K and 3L (the same exception is thrown for that job too). The JobParameters I use are the following: **EDIT**: I've included a Random function in order to include a unique JobParameter:

```
Random randomizer = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

params1 = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString(PROCESS, "Job 3K BAR" )
        .addString("pos_cod", "BAR")
        .addString("per_event", "EVENT")
        .addString(IS_RET, FALSE)
        .addLong("UNIQUE", randomizer.nextLong())
        .toJobParameters();

params2 = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString(PROCESS, "Job 3K 704" )
        .addString("pos_cod", "704")
        .addString("per_event", "EVENT")
        .addString(IS_RET, FALSE)
        .addLong("UNIQUE", randomizer.nextLong())
        .toJobParameters();

params3 = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString(PROCESS, "Job 3L BAR" )
        .addString("pos_cod", "BAR")
        .addString("per_event", "RET_EVENT")
        .addString(IS_RET, FALSE)
        .addLong("UNIQUE", randomizer.nextLong())
        .toJobParameters();
params4 = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString(PROCESS, "Job 3L 704" )
        .addString("pos_cod", "704")
        .addString("per_event", "RET_EVENT")
        .addString(IS_RET, FALSE)
        .addLong("UNIQUE", randomizer.nextLong())
        .toJobParameters();
```

Having seen the duplicated job instance error keeps occurring as the JobLauncher is trying to launch the samen job (not its sibling with other JobParameters), I'm more inclined to think this is a problem with my JobRepository, but this is nothing more than speculation.

Comment: Which JobRepository implementation do you use? Please share its config as well as the configuration of the transaction manager.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine for the fast response. I'm using the default configured JobRepository and TransactionManager, so I got no special ocnfiguration. Should I be using a specific config? If so, where I can find an example for both? (preferably with Java Config)

Answer (score 0):

The `Map` based job repository is [not intended](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html) for multi-threading. This job repository is by default configured with a `ResourcelessTransactionManager`.

Make sure to use the JDBC based job repository (even with an in-memory database like in your case) to properly support multi-threading and parallel processing along with a `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

As a side note, the `SimpleDriverDataSource` is not a pooled data source, I recommend to use one with a connection pool.

Comment: I've added the configuration you suggested but I'm facing a new problem I'm not quite sure how to fix yet. So it would be appreciated if you could have a look again. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Glad to see the first issue fixed! For the second issue, please note that the `JobParametersIncrementer` (`RunIdIncrementer` in your case) is not called when you use the job launcher. It is only called when you use the  `CommandLineJobRunner` with “-next” option or with `JobOperator#startNextInstance`. So in your case, you need to add a unique parameter yourself in the job parameters before calling the jobLauncher in order to create a new job instance.

Comment: I tried to introduce a new unique parameter in each JobParameter for the 3K & 3L, but it's still no working as intended. I added some new log results and updated code on my original question. Thanks and regards